# Pointer does not work

Tags: c++

I am new to C++. I am trying to run the following code hoping to get

> Name: Matthew
>   Receptionist: John

However, it gave me:

> Name: Matthew
>   Receptionist: none

I thought that by setting pointer `r` to `receptionist` in the `set_receptionist(Employee* r)` function, I made `receptionist` pointer point to the `Employee` object, which is also the pointee of `r`.

So, by using arrow operator, I thought that I could access to the member function of `Employee` object to which receptionist is pointing.

Please correct me if my understanding is wrong. And teach me how I could fix this code to get the result I want to get.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Employee
{
public:
    string getName();
    void setName(string);
private:
    string name;
};

string Employee::getName()
{
    return name;
}

void Employee::setName(string x)
{
    name = x;
}

class Department
{
public:
    Department(string);
    void set_receptionist(Employee*);
    void print();
private:
    string name;
    Employee* receptionist;
};

Department::Department(string a)
{
    name = a;
    receptionist = NULL;
}

void Department::set_receptionist(Employee* r)
{
    receptionist = r;
}

void Department::print()
{
    cout << "Name: " << name << "\nReceptionist: ";
    if (receptionist == NULL)
        cout << "none";
    else
        cout << receptionist->getName();
    cout << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    Employee e;
    e.setName("John");

    Department d("Matthew");
    d.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to call `set_receptionist`: `d.set_receptionist(&e);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never actually invoke the `Department::set_receptionist` method. So since `receptionist` starts as `NULL` in the `Department` constructor, it remains `NULL` when you call `Department::print`.

```
Employee john;
john.setName("John");
Department d("Matthew");
d.set_receptionist(&john);
d.print();
```

To answer your comment, a pointer is a type which can store an address to another variable. That's exactly what it means to be a pointer. Pointers are variables that point at other variables. The way you tell the pointer where to point is by assigning an address to that pointer.

So when you say the following:

```
Employee john;
Employee *pointer = &john;
```

The variable `pointer` is now pointing at the variable `john` by storing its address. You can "dereference" a pointer to get at the original pointed variable which in this case is `john`. So saying `pointer->setName("Bob");` is just like saying `john.setName("Bob");` except you're doing it via a pointer now. It's important to realize that `*pointer` is not a **copy** of `john`, but actually references the same memory location as `john`. Thus any modifications that you make through `*pointer` apply directly to `john` and will be visible in `john`.

This diagram may help you visually understand the relationships between pointers and variables:

[image]

Comment: So, should I crate an object of Department like
Department d; in main and call
d.set_receptionist()?

Comment: Sorry, but I am still confused. Where and how should I invoke the set_receptionist?

Comment: OMG it worked! Thank you so much!!!
so, basically, I needed to pass the &ObjectOfEmployee to the set_receptionist(Employee* r) function.
Could you please tell me why passing the address of Employee's object will be equivalent to pointer r of type Employee?

Comment: I think I understood now. The pointer r holds the address of Employee obj, so passing Employee obj's address &e created in main will be equivalent to r!
Thank you so much for your help!!!

Comment: Sorry to ask again. When I did not pass in "John" from main, I was hoping to get "none" for the receptionist, but it gave me just a blank space. I realized that receptionist is no longer pointing to NULL when we set the address of Employee object in set_receptionist(Employee* r) function, so this could be causing the problem. How could I fix this problem?

Comment: Oh, never mind, I solved that problem! thanks so much!